# To get Content of next TD based on CheckBox selection

Tags: jquery, html

Am having a HTML Table

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="Checkbox" name="check"/></td>
    <td>random text1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="Checkbox" name="check"/></td>
    <td>random text 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="Checkbox" name="check"/></td>
    <td>random text 4</td>
</tr>
```

---

On button Click i need to get the value of  next to the checkbox in case the checkbox is selected as list.

```
var selectedArray = [];
var selected = new Object();
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    selectedAttributes = $(this).closest('td').next().html();
    if (this.checked)
        searchAttibutes.push(selectedAttributes);
});
```

This code works fine and returns me the Array of text on next `<td>` text

```
//o/p [random text1,random text 2]  -- assuming first 2 checkbox selected
```

---

Alternatively

```
var selectedArray = [];
var selected = new Object();
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    selectedAttributes.random = $(this).closest('td').next().html();
    if (this.checked)
        searchAttibutes.push(selectedAttributes);
});
```

Will alway return the Array if Last `<td>` text on total number of text box selected

```
//o/p [Object { random="random text 4"}, Object { random="random text 4"}]  -- assuming first 2 checkbox selected
```

---

Why am getting different o/p in  both the traversals?

Comment: Small correction **not equal** instead it is **semi-colon** `[Object { random:"random text 4"}, Object { random:"random text 4"}]`

Comment: @Praveen Agree with the Syntax but this is how Mozilla displays if i console:)

Answer (score 1):

different o/p is not because of traversal, it is *based on the way you're handling the variable in the loop.*

### Method#1

```
selectedAttributes = $(this).closest('td').next().html();
```

Here `selectedAttributes` is a variable

> o/p:
>   random text1
>   random text2
>   // selectedArray = [random text1,random text 2] 
>   and this you're pushing it into array.

### Method#2

whereas here,

```
selectedAttributes.random = $(this).closest('td').next().html();
```

you're creating `searchAttibutes` as an **`object`** and **`random`** is your `key` and assigning value to it.

> o/p:
>   {random: random text1}
>   {random: random text2}
>   // [Object { random:"random text 4"}, Object { random:"random text 4"}]

and this `object` you're pushing it into array.

Hope you understood.

Comment: Thanks.I need to push the object to Array with this concept. is there way i can change the each function of checked to make the second method work ?

Comment: @Peru I don't get the point of pushing to array, since it is already does.  Can you elaborate more?